# PHP - Calling a static function from an object instance works?

Tags: php, oop, static

I just wrote a sample class to better understand the static methods and variables in PHP. I understand how the static variables work but the static function is not working as expected. If you see the below code

```
class Car{
    static $wheels=4;
    static function getWheels(){
        echo Car::$wheels=10;
    }
}
$car1 = new Car();
$car1->getWheels();
```

I was expecting

```
$car1->getWheels(); to throw and error since getWheels is a static method.
```

Why is this not throwing an error or warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it comes from the PHP 4 times, where there was no `static` keyword but you could call static methods whether with the `->`  or the `::` operator

In fact, tecnically speaking, calling `$car1->getWheels()` was (and is) translated by PHP to `Car::getWheels()` at run time

With the advent of PHP5 this option was mantained for backward compatibility purposes

If you enable `E_STRICT` error reporting though, this should raise a warning now